# Geonames - Get Closest Cities by Population and Specific Country

Tags: php, geonames

I'm using the GEONEMAES API to query CANADIAN cities.  However when connecting to this endpoint:

```
 http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=48.9937&lng=-122.74&style=short&radius=30&maxRows=30&cities=cities1000&username=demo
```

I can't get just the list of cities from CANADA.  Instead I get both USA and CANADA cities.

What parameter should I send to the API in order to:

1. Get a list of cities of an specific Country.
2. Order the list of cities by parameters, for example by it's population.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do it with your example. But there is also parameter `localCountry`. Your example returns cities from US only. If you will set coordinates to search within Canada, then you can get list that you want:

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=49.01636&lng=-122.74&style=short&radius=30&localCountry=true&maxRows=30&cities=cities1000&username=demo